# Cannot refresh token

Tags: html

When I wanna refresh my token I keep getting this error

```
{
  "data": {
    "error": "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing",
    "request": "\/oauth2\/token",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "success": false,
  "status": 400
}
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: How do you send the request? Provide minimal working code example.

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. I'd strongly recommend to see this link [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add more details in your question so we can help you.